# Как обновить только некоторые элементы в шаблоне, а не всю страницу?

Tags: html, django

Какой метод следует использовать для того чтобы обновлять только некоторые элементы, а не всю страницу - при срабатывании запроса.

Страница выглядит следующим

[image: образом]

И при выборе в фильтрах `Rating` - 4, срабатывает запрос - `GET`, и вся страница обновляется.
Как можно реализовать обновление только для определенных объектов (товаров на странице, и ничего кроме этого)

---

Использую Django Oscar,

Comment: Абстрактно: используйте JavaScript и AJAX. То есть применение фильтров должно обновлять не всю страницу, а должно неким образом обрабатываться в JavaScript (считывать фильтры, формировать и отправлять запрос к серверу, получать ответ и парсить его, размещать результат на странице).

Comment: @Chikiro Там это используется(JavaScript и AJAX) - но обновляет всю страницу по запросу GET, вы не могли бы скинуть примеры или как весь этот метод называется ?

Comment: @Chikiro а вы не могли бы примерно представить в коде, данное решение - возможно уже есть какие то готовы решения ? И я не совсем уверен что нужно парсить и размещать(хотя вам может виднее), просто когда идет запрос в строку - selectedfacets, то Джанго автоматом парсит и готовит вьюху, вот только не обновляет(помоему).

Comment: К сожалению подробнее ничего не могу рассказать, ничего не знаю об Oscar, и есть ли в нем подобные встроенные возможности.